# What is the "point" of root node in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx

Why `Scene` object needs to have a **root node**? Why `Scene` object can't be just a placeholder for collection of nodes without them being nested under the root one?

Comment: The `root` is a `Node`, and has all the properties that other nodes have. The `Scene` is not a `Node`, presumably because it needs properties that nodes don't need (e.g. a `camera`) and doesn't need properties that `Node`s have (bounds, transforms, layout coordinates, etc.). But you're asking here for us to guess the minds of the designers of the API, which is going to make this question primarily opinion based.

Comment: And if you could place an arbitrary number of `Node`s directly in the scene, then `Scene` would need a layout mechanism. That would either require replicating code (because `Node` subclasses already have a layout mechanism) or factoring layout into classes separate from the scene graph hierarchy, which is simply not the design choice that was made. Swing/AWT uses that mechanism, and many of the JavaFX API designers worked extensively on Swing, so that choice was made with a considerable amount of experience.

Answer (score 4):

From [Understanding the JavaFX Architecture](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/get-started-tutorial/jfx-architecture.htm)<sup>1</sup>

> The JavaFX scene graph ... is a hierarchical tree of nodes that represents all of the visual elements of the application's user interface

A tree of nodes must have a single, root node.
Each node must have a parent node – except, of-course, for the root node.

<sup>1</sup> Part of Oracle's JavaFX tutorials.